# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ClassType'

Tags: python, attributeerror

Ok so I've been trying to type the command: python
but it ends up spitting this out:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site.py", line 62, in <module>
    import os
  File "C:\Python27\lib\os.py", line 398, in <module>
    import UserDict
  File "C:\Python27\lib\UserDict.py", line 83, in <module>
    import _abcoll
  File "C:\Python27\lib\_abcoll.py", line 70, in <module>
    Iterable.register(str)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\abc.py", line 107, in register
    if not isinstance(subclass, (type, types.ClassType)):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ClassType'
```

I renamed the types.py to nottypes.py but it is still giving me the exact same message.

Comment: It would help if you included your code.

Comment: I included the code...

Comment: No, you included the code from the Python standard library. `abc.py` is not at fault here, so I removed it again; we don't want to end up relicensing PSF-code to CC Wiki here.

Comment: @InbarRose: This has nothing to do with the standard library code. The user has a `types.py` file in the local directory.

Comment: I don't get it... Can you give me a path to the local directory that has the types.py?

Comment: @user2594359 He means you created a file named types.py. Rename it.

Comment: It's giving me the exact same error, even after I renamed the types.py to nottypes.py

Answer (score 16):

You've called something else in `sys.path` "types.py". Rename it.

Comment: I renamed it to nottypes.py and it is still giving me the same error message! Do I have to reboot my computer or something?

Comment: Remove the .pyc file too.

Comment: So obvious when one actually reads and understands the error. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

In python 3, ClassType was removed from `types`. You can use `isinstance(var_name, type)` instead.